# How do I write this php code?

Tags: php, loops, foreach

How do I write this out properly?

```
$loccity=array("Atlanta","Boston");

foreach ($loccity as $city) {
   $myurl = 'http://$city.mysite.com';
   echo $myurl;
}
```

1. Can I just stick $city in the middle of $myurl like that?
2. Will using a `foreach` loop like this work in this way or is a counter needed?

Comment: Voting to close. You can test that yourself and you will know! Not a real question!

Comment: @markus: It _is_ a real question, even though the answer is easily deducible.

Comment: Variable interpolation works but only with double quotes, a foreach loop is the perfect choice. Even better then interpolation (smelly) would be to use sprintf.

Comment: @markus: That might be better off as an _answer_, not a comment.

Comment: @Tomalak: It may be a real question... if yes, then it's a xlicate and still has to be closed. It's also a RTM question IMO.

Comment: @Tomalak: I don't think this shold be a question, so I don't write an answer. I don't rep whoring when I want to close a question.

Comment: @markus: If it's a duplicate, find the question it's a duplicate of and vote to close accordingly. "Not a question" is clearly false!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 2. Will using a `foreach` loop like this work in this way or is a counter needed?

Yes, it'll work properly.

> 1. Can I just stick $city in the middle of $myurl like that?

Almost.

You forgot that variable interpolation doesn't work with single quotes, but with double quotes:

```
<?php
$loccity = array("Atlanta", "Boston");

foreach ($loccity as $city) {
   $myurl = "http://$city.mysite.com";
   echo $myurl;
}

// Output: http://Atlanta.mysite.comhttp://Boston.mysite.com
?>
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/igV4Z2Gg)

---

You may also want a newline between items:

```
<?php
$loccity = array("Atlanta", "Boston");

foreach ($loccity as $city) {
   echo "http://$city.mysite.com\n";
}

// Output:
// http://Atlanta.mysite.com
// http://Boston.mysite.com
?>
```

[Live demo.](http://codepad.org/Mu45bPLt)

Comment: You were right.. the double quotes not being there was causing my problem.  But it wasn't because I forgot.  I didn't know!  :)  Thanks so much.  I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Andi: Not a problem. FWIW, this is all covered in the [admittedly poorly structured] **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)** .. which of course you've read several times I hope?! :)

Comment: I go there all the time.  Unfortunately, I am a terrible programmer.. which bugs the crap out of me because I love this stuff.  When I try to apply something I read to my own example, I seem to usually fail.  :(  But.. I will keep trying.  :)

Comment: @Andi: You're certainly on the way there.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your single quotes with double quotes.

For good measure, wrap your '$city' in curly brackets. So `"http://{$city}.mysite.com/"`

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't it work? Just use double quotes when using $variable inside text

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/466fd.php

```
<?php
$loccity=array("Atlanta","Boston");

foreach ($loccity as $city) {
    $myurl = "http://$city.mysite.com<br>";
    echo $myurl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This was my problem and why I asked the question.  People above were jumping on me that I could easily test.  I did and was getting an error that it didn't work.  I didn't realize I had to wrap it in double quotes if using a variable inside.

Comment: If I helped you, please help me: when possible, **[accept my answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6V5xR.gif)** (click on that link if you're not sure how to do so)

Comment: @genesis: "newbie" has already accepted answers to five questions before this one!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: ... I just wanted to say it's not begging. I place these comments only when there is comment from OP like "Thanks"

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $loccity=array("Atlanta","Boston");

 foreach ($loccity as $city) {
 $myurl = 'http://'.$city.'.mysite.com';
 echo $myurl;
 }
 ?>
```

. operator is concatenation operator.
`output`
`http://Atlanta.mysite.comhttp://Boston.mysite.com`